# Ubuntu 18.04 How to Install Themes for Applications

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell

[image]

I am a newcomer for Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME Shell 3.28.2 (libgtk-2.24.32 and libgtk-3.22.30).

I installed `CommuniTheme` and it added 'Communitheme' options for `Cursor` and `Icons` under `Themes` as shown in the screenshot above. However, it does not add such an option for `Applications.`

I like flat style of Icons provided by `CommuniTheme` so I want application windows, especially title bars, to look something like that.

I tried several User themes, e.g., [Arc Theme Mod](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1242554/), but they change only `Cursor` and `Icons` but `Applicatoins`.

How can I change an application theme?

Comment: **How** did you install CommuniTheme?

Comment: @pomsky I did `sudo snap install communitheme`.

Comment: Reboot your system, when you get to the GDM login screen, click the cogwheel/gear icon next to the "sign in" button. Choose "Ubuntu Communitheme" and log in.

Comment: @pomsky I tried `sudo apt install ubuntu-communitheme-session` because you raised a question! (https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-community-theme/) I do not know why but it is working now. Thank you!